# Swift Dictionary involving Array Declaration

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I cannot access to array in dictionary.

```
print (fastWay["superMarket"][0])
```

Various declaration type have been tested.

eg:

```
var fastWay: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]

let roadMap = [
"home": ["hair": 5, "super": 10, "academy": 9],
"hair": ["home": 5, "super": 3, "bank": 11],
"superMarket":["hairShop":3, "home":10, "englishAcademy":7, "restaurant":3],
"englishAcademy": ["home":9, "superMarket":7, "school":12],
"restaurant" :      ["superMarket":3, "bank":4],
"bank" :            ["hairShop":11, "restaurant":4, "englishAcademy":7, "school":2],
"school" : ["bank":2, "englishAcademy":12]]

print (roadMap["home"]?["academy"])

var fastWay: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    for i in roadMap.keys{
fastWay.updateValue([false, 9999, "start"], forKey: i)}

print (fastWay)
print (fastWay["superMarket"][0])
```

Xcode Playground comment:
Value of optional type 'Any?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'Any'

Comment: Why not `var fastWay: [String: [Any]] = [:]` since you want a dictionary with string keys and values that are an array of `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value inside the dictionary is of Any type, you cant access the subscript because the compiler cant know if this value type can handle it.

You just need to cast the value type to an array of objects then you can access them:

```
var fastWay: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
for i in roadMap.keys{
    fastWay.updateValue([false, 9999, "start"], forKey: i)
}

print (fastWay)

if let parsed = fastWay["superMarket"] as? [Any] {
   //access any value you want
    print(parsed[0])
}
```

Comment: Is there a another way to access the value inside the dictionary? (e.g. another declaration script). Because I'm trying to construct an algorithm using the dictionary inside value.

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean by another way, but you can declare your dictionary "Dictionary<String, [Any]>" and this will allow you to access its values like this: fastWay["home"]?[0]